# Just wanna ask if its okay to use did + ing or continues form verb.

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

> I did passing the files yesterday.

Is it correct?

I'm so confused right now.  I know that using did should comes with present verb right?

Comment: Please provide examples and contexts

Comment: It is not okay, did should come with a plain verb

Comment: Just want to ask if it's okay to use....

Comment: We don't use **_wanna_** in polite English. Some people may even think it is rude, and it does not create a good impression of you except in informal settings, such as text messaging between friends. Use **_want to_** instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you use *do* (or any other auxiliary like *might* or *shall* or *could*) in a sentence, you conjugate the *do* and use the **bare infinitive** of the other verb.  Not the present tense, although they often look similar!

Examples:

- He eats.  /  He *does eat*.
- We ate. / We *did eat*.

If you want to use a *continuous* tense, with a gerund like "passing", you have to use a form of *to be*, not *to do*.

Examples:

- I pass.  / I *am passing*.
- She passed.  / She *was passing*.

References:

- [DO, DOES, DID + bare infinitive](http://www.grammaring.com/do-does-did-bare-infinitive)
- [Present Continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html)
- [Past Continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html)